# Query in SSRS- How do I JOIN one table to another matching only data in the middle of the column

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm Trying to JOIN tables based on matching contract numbers, however the first table has the word "contract" before the number and a bunch of spaces after the number.  I cant seem to figure how to do this in a query and I also attempted to do it with expressions (which I was able to do, but I couldn't then properly place a filter to display only the rows that matched). Please Help!

I'm trying to JOIN the Contract Number (column name "TRXDSCRN") in my Billings Table (table name "RM20101") to an identical Contract Number (column name "Contract_Number") in my Service Table (table name "SV00500").  The TRXDSCRN column needs a filter of some sort to cut the word "contract" from the beginning of it's data, match the next 10 letters and numbers (which is the contract number), and then drop any spaces afterwords.

Please let me know if you need any information I'm leaving out.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** It should be SUBSTRING for MS SQL. SUBSTR is MySQL. Sorry for the confusion.

---

If I understand properly I think what you are referring to is:

```
SELECT * FROM RM20101 as RM20101
LEFT JOIN SV00500 as SV00500
ON SUBSTR(RM20101.TRXDSCRN,9,10) = SV00500.Contract_Number
```

To explain, the piece you really need is the SUBSTR() portion. What this says is take the column, RM20101.TRXDSCRN, *start* in the 9th position, and *end* after 10 characters. The reason you start with the 9th position is because 'contract' is 8 characters long. Of course, you end after 10 characters because the contract is 10 characters long as you stated.

If you have any questions about it or it doesn't quite meet all of your needs, let me know.

Comment: I just tried this and received Error Message: 'SUBSTR' is not a recognized built in function name

Comment: Thanks! I used SUBSTRING and it worked.  My next question.  There are many NULL lines that were brought in as well.  (because there are data lines with nothing as a contract number matching a "NULL" to a "NULL"...Is there a simple way to get these taken out?

Comment: You can try this: "ON SUBSTR(RM20101.TRXDSCRN,9,10) = SV00500.Contract_Number OR TRXDSCRN IS NULL AND Contract_Number IS NULL" or "ON ISNULL(SUBSTR(RM20101.TRXDSCRN,9,10),0) = ISNULL(SV00500.Contract_Number,0)". But the first approach is better - the second one will not use index (if it's built on this column) and can join uncorrectly contracts when you have NULL in one column and 0 value in the second

Comment: I am sorry about the SUBSTR thing. I am glad it worked for you. Did Konza piece help you with filtering out NULLs? If the answer has satisfied your question, please make sure to mark it as answered :)